# How can I get the coordinates of an axis label to anchor to it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw an arrow with relation to an axis label, like "x —>". The arrow shall be a line with a customized arrowhead showing in the direction of the axis.

Thanks in advance for any support.
Frank

Comment: Perhaps show us a quick manual drawing, such as a scan.

Comment: ^ plus minimal working example (MWE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following option uses the `pin` option to an empty label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  label arrow/.style={
    pin={[pin edge={->,thin,draw=black}]0:},
  },
]
\begin{axis}[
  width=100mm,
  height=80mm,
  xmin=0, xmax=.5,
  xlabel=$x$,
  x label style={label arrow},
  ymin = 0, ymax=.5,
  ylabel=$y$,
  y label style={label arrow},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The length of the arrow line can be configured by `pin distance`:

```
label arrow/.style={
  pin={[pin distance=7mm, pin edge={->,thin,draw=black}]0:},
},
```

Answer (score 5):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
             xlabel=$x$,
             x label style={alias=thexlabel} % <-- makes thexlabel a name for the xlabel node
            ]
\end{axis}
\draw [-stealth] (thexlabel.east) -- +(1cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a `scope` used for scaling around `axis` and arrows, this doesn't work very well it seems. Too late in the evening to think hard on the problem, but a simple workaround may be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\scalefactor}{1.5}
\begin{axis}[width=\scalefactor*100mm,height=\scalefactor*80mm, xmin = 0,xmax = 0.5, xlabel=$x$, x label style={alias=xlbl}, ymin = 0,ymax = 0.5, ylabel=$y$, y label style={rotate=-90,alias=ylbl}]
\end{axis} 
\begin{scope}[scale=\scalefactor]
\draw [->] (xlbl.east) -- +(7mm,0);
\draw [->] (ylbl.north) -- +(0,7mm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works very nicely, but does not scale with the value set in the scope environment. Why is it crucial that "draw [-stealth] (thexlabel.east) -- +(1cm,0);" has to be outside the axis environment? Best Regards. Frank

Comment: @Franklin Hope you didn't expect me to know that you had a `scope` environment with a `scale` option. Need some more information about your setup though, scaling worked with my simple test. Not quite sure why it has be outside, but it may appear that the xlabel is only defined at the end of the `axis`, so when trying to access it before it doesn't work.

Comment: @ Torbjørn. Thanks again. Here is my code. If you change the scaling factor inside "scope" you will see what happens.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=1.50]
\begin{axis}[width=100mm,height=80mm,
    xmin = 0,xmax = 0.5,
             xlabel=$x$,
             x label style={alias=xlbl},
    ymin = 0,ymax = 0.5,
             ylabel=$y$,
             y label style={rotate=-90,alias=ylbl},
\end{axis}
\draw [->] (xlbl.east) -- +(7mm,0);
\draw [->] (ylbl.north) -- +(0,7mm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @Franklin Updated my answer with a workaround of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to all. My problem is solved. Here is a final example with arrow heads and diagramm framework settings (arrow heads, line widths, tick lenghts) according to DIN specifications.
Yours
Frank

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%-----TikZ--------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{pgf}
%-----pgfplots----------------------------
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%-----Color Definition -------------------
\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.65,0.00,0.00}
%-----DIN Arrow Head----------------------
\pgfarrowsdeclare{DIN}{DIN}{
  \arrowsize=10\pgflinewidth
  \advance\arrowsize by -10\pgflinewidth
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-10\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}{\arrowsize=10\pgflinewidth
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} %  do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin   %  fix join
\pgfsetroundcap    %  fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1\arrowsize}{0.13165\arrowsize}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1\arrowsize}{-0.13165\arrowsize}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfillstroke
 %\pgfusepathqstroke
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfusepathqstroke}
%=================================================*
\begin{document}
%-------------------------------------------------
begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
xlabel arrow/.style={
    pin={[pin distance=7mm, pin edge={-DIN,line width=0.25mm,draw=black}]0:},},
ylabel arrow/.style={
    pin={[pin distance=7mm, pin edge={-DIN,line width=0.25mm,draw=black}]90:}}]
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=0.35mm,
tick style={minor tick num=1,line width=0.18mm,minor tick length = 1.25mm, major tick length = 2.5mm, color=Black}}}
\begin{scope}[scale=1.00]
\begin{axis}[width=100mm,height=80mm,
    clip mode=individual,
    xmin = -1.5,xmax = 1.5,
        xlabel=$x$,
        xlabel style = {alias=xlbl, xlabel arrow},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,use comma,/tikz/.cd},
    ymin = 0,ymax = 1,
             ylabel=$p$,
             y label style={rotate=-90,alias=ylbl, ylabel arrow},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,use comma,/tikz/.cd},
             ]
\addplot[DarkRed,line width = 0.7mm,samples=201,smooth,line cap=round,domain=-1.5:1.5]{((1/(0.425*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((x-0.2)/0.425)^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%-------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%=================================================*
```